# Where is the error in the else position in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, xcode, flutter-qrcode

[image]

At first, I was told that PrettyQrView was wrong, so I changed PrettyQrView(qrCode: qrData) to PrettyQrView.data(data: qrData), and this error disappeared, but the error in else is still the same. I don't know if it's a location issue, but even if I move the location, the error remains the same.

I wanted to fix the error in else and create a code that generates a QR code containing the ID used when the user logs in.

Comment: Please share your code in text instead of a print-screen. For more guidance with your question, please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try removing the comma just before the else.  the if-true branch can be only a single expression, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [control flow collection proposal](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/main/accepted/2.3/control-flow-collections/feature-specification.md), you can use if-else inside a collection with a syntax like this:

```dart
if (cond) expr1 else expr2
```

Notice how there's no comma (`,`) before the `else` keyword.

So in order to make your code works, modify it to follow the syntax:

```dart
if (qrData.isNotEmpty)
  PrettyQrView.data(data: qrData)
else
  Text('There is ...')
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the **conditional operator** (known as **ternary operator** in other languages):

```dart
qrData.isNotEmpty
    ? PrettyQrView.data(data: qrData)
    : Text('There is ...')
```

Comment: You can use if-else inside a collection...

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the comma, so not

```
if(qrData.isNotEmpty) ..., else
```

but

```
if(qrData.isNotEmpty) ... else
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use somthing like this

```
if ( condition_is_true )
    your_widget_here
else ... [
    your_widget_here
],
```

or if it's list of widgets you can do like this

```
if ( condition_is_true ) ... [
    your_widget_here 
    your_widget_here
    your_widget_here
]
else ... [
    your_widget_here
    your_widget_here
    your_widget_here
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

`if(condition)...[]` `else <conditional widget>`